# Symlink error "This location could not be displayed"

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, permissions, symbolic-link

Just upgraded to 14.04 (and it wasn't super easy, had a number of issues to fix...)

I have a few external hard drives with video files. In my `~/Videos/ directory` I had symlinks to those drives created by using the `ln -s` command.

Before the upgrade, they were working fine. After the upgrade I'm getting an error

```
"This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of 'DRIVE NAME'.
```

I get the same error for all three drives. If I create a symlink to a local directory it works fine.

Right clicking on the symlink and selecting "properties" tells me Link target: `/media/DRIVE NAME/` (which looks right), and says `Contents: unreadable`.

I've tried deleting & recreating the links, with no change.

I have also turned on the "Local Network Share" folder sharing, but I don't know that that makes any difference. (I turned it on to share with the network, not to fix this problem)

The drives seem to be working perfectly. When I click on them under "Devices" I can view them and use the files like normal. When I click on the symlink I get the error, then a blank page.

I don't know if this is a symptom of the system upgrade having problems, the newer version just doing things differently, or a new bug.

I'm comfortable with IT, but new to Ubuntu - so I really appreciate any help that can walk me through the solution, as I don't yet know what diagnostic tools or strategies are available :)

Comment: I don't think symbolic links across devices are easy to manage unless you're mounting the devices manually. Nevertheless, have you first opened the drive in Nautilus?

Comment: I'm using unity, and the drives seem to open under Nautilus when they are plugged in. Even when booting with the drives already plugged in they used to work fine, but that might be because I always kept the same drives plugged in. Using Gunnar's suggestion below seems to have fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/media/DRIVE NAME/` does not look right to me. In Ubuntu 14.04 external disks are typically mounted as `/media/USERNAME/DRIVENAME/`.

Comment: Thanks! Making a symlink including Username worked perfectly! (For some reason, the tab autocomplete will allow /media/DRIVE NAME and even autocomplete the correct drive names. Making it /media/USERNAME/DRIVE NAME solves the problem)